# Problem with contact/intersection shader with Unity3d Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

I am relatively new to shader graph and I struggle with one thing : making correct intersection shader with two sided material.

Here are some pictures of what is happening

Without two sided
[image: Without two sided]

With two sided
[image: With two sided]

My issue is that we can't see the contact effect from the back of the mesh, but when I  activate it, the transparency is not working for the back faces...

Here is my full shader graph:

Full Shader Graph
[image: Full Shader Graph]

(Two sided isn't active because I'd rather use it without than with the non-transparent sphere)

I just want some help to understand why the transparency isn't working when the full contact shader is.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the solution so I share it here.

The problem was the fresnel effect that wasn't working with two sided objects, but now it does with this little trick.

[image]